# Creating a permanent link to a code snippet

Tags: gitea

I would like to create permalinks to code snippets (like in Github). 
Is there a way to create a permalink to a code snippet with Gitea?

Comment: unfortunatelly the option to press 'y' as described at https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-files-in-a-repository/getting-permanent-links-to-files#press-kbdykbd-to-permalink-to-a-file-in-a-specific-commit does not work and the options as described at https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/creating-a-permanent-link-to-a-code-snippet are not available